# Serial.available() still reading data despite no input

Tags: arduino, i2c

so I made a circuit which sends an analogue signal through a DAC using I2C and then reads back an analogue signal through an ADC. However, I'm getting an unexpected output from the below code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP4725.h>
#define voltsIn A0

Adafruit_MCP4725 dac; // constructor

uint32_t dac_value=0;
uint8_t adcValueRead[3] = {};  
int16_t result=0;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  dac.begin(0x60);  
}

void loop(void) {
    if (Serial.available()>0) {
      dac_value=Serial.parseInt()

      Wire.beginTransmission(0x6A);
      Wire.write(0xA8);
      Wire.endTransmission();

      delay(1000);
      Wire.requestFrom(0x6A, 3);
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        adcValueRead[i]=Wire.read();
      }


      result = (( ( (int16_t)(adcValueRead[0]) ) << 8) + adcValueRead[1]);

      Serial.print(result*0.0000625);

       delay(500);
    }
}
```

So the output I expect when I input 0 should be:

-2.05 (that's just the lower limit of the ADC).

Instead my output is:

-2.05 (delay) -2.05

Then when my input is 2048, my output is:

0 (delay) -2.05

Inputting 4095 gives me:

2.05 (delay) -2.05

So from what I understand, after the arduino reads my input the first time, the value 0 is then left inside the serial port which then triggers the if statement. First, I'm just wondering why the serial port would act that way and how I might be able to circumvent the issue so it only prints one value for one input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending carriage returns or line breaks after your input number, they will still be in the `Serial` buffer after `parseInt` runs.

When `parseInt` runs again, it cannot parse these characters and returns `0`, which is then processed by your code.

There is no way to tell the difference between `parseInt` parsing an actual `0` characters and this error condition. Possible solutions:

- Send your integers without any trailing characters
- Use a different method of conversion (`strtol` or `atoi` for example)
- Clear the incoming serial buffer after each read, like this:

```
while (Serial.available())
{
    Serial.read();
}
```